# <ol><li> tags problem insise asp:repeater

Tags: c#, repeater

i have small problems with asp:Repeater. I am printing `<ol><li>` tags inside repeater in one line. How can i print it in two lines like:

```
- test   - test2
- test3  - test4
- test5  - test6
...
```

now is like

```
- test
- test2
- test3
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try putting a CssClass attribute on you repeater, and use a simple CSS :

```
.myRepeaterCssClass ol li {
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: hi, nice idea. I will try and let you know. Thx